# ExtJS Grid PagingToolbar refresh on store remove

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I've setup a ExtJS Grid, while using the PagingToolbar (with PagingMemoryProxy on an ArrayStore).

I have removed items from the store of the grid, but the PagingToolbar will not show that the items have been removed.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unbinding and rebinding the store when you modify the items.

```
myGrid.store.on('remove', function() {
  var pager = myGrid.getBottomToolbar();
  if (pager) {
    pager.unbind(myGrid.store);
    pager.bind(myGrid.store);
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not work correctly when using PagingMemoryProxy on an ArrayStore.